# AdwhirlView not displaying an ad -- but the view seems to be there

Tags: iphone, ios4, admob, adwhirl

Trying to integrate adwhirl into my application and currently have admob set up. The AdwhirlView gets added to the view but an ad is never displayed or received (I know the view is there because the cgrect where I place the adview is on top of a button.. which doesn't work with the view on top of it).

Here is what I have so far following the adwhirl instructions
I've implemented the two required delegate functions:

```
- (NSString *)adWhirlApplicationKey {
    return @"mystring";
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForPresentingModalView {
    return self;
}
```

And I also have this in my viewcontrollers viewdidload method:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    adwhirlview = [AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];
    [adwhirlview setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 361.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f)];
    [self.view addSubview:adwhirlview];
}
```

Where adwhirlview is an instance variable to the viewcontroller.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any networks enabled in AdWhirl?

You should at least enable the "House Ads" network, and add some house ads.

On the network page, be sure to hit the "save" button at the very bottom!  This button isn't visible on my wide laptop screen and I had no idea I had to press it (considering that the network "ON|OFF" toggle has a "save changes" button too.

AdWhirl will not display any error message to you if you simply have no networks enabled – which I think is a bit of a usability bug...